# Using declare statement in drl files

Tags: drools, declare

I am declaring a SensorMode object in the DRL file

```
declare SensorMode
  modeOffset: Integer
end
```

I have set the value to modeOffset using

```
FactType factType=kbase.getFactType("com.yob.pestway.
valueobjects",  "SensorMode");
Object nc = factType.newInstance(); 
factType.set(nc, "modeOffset",sensorDataVO.getModeOffset());
```

I need to use the modeOffset in the following rule,It gives me an error saying $mode.modeOffset is not visible.

```
rule "Difference in offsets"
dialect "java"
no-loop true
when
    $mode:SensorMode();
    $snrData : SensorDataVO(getWeightOffset().size()>0,
    $initOffset:getInitialOffset());
then
    System.out.println("---modeOffset---"+$mode.modeOffset);
    update($snrData);
end
```

Can you please suggest

Comment: Did you try "mvel" dialect ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two alternatives:

```
rule "Difference in offsets"
dialect "java"
no-loop true
when
    $mode:SensorMode( $mo: modeOffset );
    //...
then
    System.out.println("---modeOffset---"+ $mo);
    //...
end
```

Or:

```
rule "Difference in offsets"
dialect "java"
no-loop true
when
    $mode:SensorMode();
    //...
then
    System.out.println("---modeOffset---"+ $mode.getModeOffset() );
    //...
end
```

It's possible that `dialect "mvel"` is a third option, but this may depend on the Drools version you are using.

Comment: Just to be clear here: if you use `dialect "java"` in a rule, you MUST use objects getters/setters in the RHS.

Comment: @EstebanAliverti A bound variable should be OK, too.